# Struggling to open a file, storing the contents then slicing the required content using ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, loops, each

I have a foo.txt file that contains the following information

```
      \\generic text 
      0: 6354
      1: 6355
      2: 6356
      \\generic text
      0: 6357
      1: 6358
      2: 6359
```

I was hoping the following code would slice the required content (numbers after :) from each line and store it.

```
      require 'FileUtils'
      contents = File.open('foo.txt', 'rb') { |f| f.read }

      stripped = contents.each_line do 
         |x| x.slice(/(?<=: )\d+/).to_i
      end
```

When using

```
      puts stripped
```

The contents array is returned without being stripped. I'm a ruby newby (as you can probably tell) so would appreciate any assistance/guidance.

Comment: What do you mean "store it"? In a file? In memory in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
stripped = contents.each_line.map { |x|
    splitted = x.split(':') 
    # return the value if the line contains a ':' sign, nil otherwise
    splitted[1].to_i if splitted.size > 1
}.compact
```

First you create an array with integers and `nil` values and then you remove the `nil` values with `compact`.

With this solution you don't even need a regular expression, because a simple `split` does the job of separating the number after the `:` from the rest of the content.

Comment: please can you explain what `splitted[1].to_i if splitted.size > 1` does? after Sawa's helpful comment I was looking for away to remove the 0's. Your script worked perfectly.

Comment: `compact` only removes nil values from the array, so the line `splitted[1].to_i if splitted.size > 1` returns a nil if the current line not contains the ':' sign (or more specific splitting with ':' results in an array with only one element) and therefore these lines can be filtered.

Comment: If i wanted to slice out both numbers before and after : I would use `stripped = contents.each_line.map { |x|
    stripped = x.slice(/^\d+\:\ \d+/)
}.compact` If I then wanted to split the numbers before and after : into a hash. should i use something like `stripped = contents.each_line.map { |x|
    stripped = x.slice(/^\d+\:\ \d+/)
    key, value = each_line.chomp.split(":")
    hash[key] = value
}.compact` ?

Comment: Used `stripped = Hash[x.scan(/(\w+): (\w+)/).map { |(first, second)| [first.to_i, second.to_i] }]` I had to remove compact and used `cleared = stripped.delete_if { |elem| elem.flatten.empty? }` to remove empty elements

Answer (score 1):

Put `.map` after `each_line`. .........................

Notice that you will get `0` between the chunks due to `nil.to_i` resulting from lines that do not match.

Answer (score 1):

There are problems with your code:

```
  require 'FileUtils'
  contents = File.open('foo.txt', 'rb') { |f| f.read }

  stripped = contents.each_line do 
     |x| x.slice(/(?<=: )\d+/).to_i
  end
```

is convoluted and will complain if the pattern doesn't match. It can be done much more simply.

You could read the file into a variable using:

```
contents = File.read('foo.txt')
```

but that can run into problems when the file grows larger than your available memory because it's "slurping" the file. Whether that's applicable to your situation only you can say, but it's something to be aware of.

I'd write the code like:

```
require 'fileutils'

contents = []
File.foreach('foo.txt') do |x|
  contents << x.slice(/(?<=: )\d+/).to_i unless x[/^\\\\/]
end
```

That doesn't slurp the file, it iterates over it line by line, which is just as fast for 99.9% of what we do. Aggregating values into `contents` still could cause problems on a huge file, but that's for another time.

```
puts contents
```

Outputs:

```
6354
6355
6356
6357
6358
6359
```

But wait, there's more! There isn't much to be gained using a regular expression to try to grab the numeric value. Instead a simple `split` on `':'` will make it easy to grab the value wanted:

```
contents << x.split(':').last.to_i unless x[/^\\\\/]
```

Substituting that in returns the same values as before.

An alternate would be to use the `scan` method:

```
contents << x.scan(/\d+/).last.to_i unless x[/^\\\\/]
```

which returns the same as above also.